# Hyperledger fabric composer transaction not working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying add this transaction named `placeOrder` i want to add a `Customer` participant 
before creating `Order` asset and map its relationship with the `Order` asset while processing this transaction. But I'm getting customer not defined error. Can anybody help? Thanks.

My models

```
namespace org.isn.customer

participant Customer identified by email {
 o String firstName
 o String lastName
 o String email
 o String password
}

enum Status{
    o ACTIVE
    o OFF_THE_ROAD  
}

asset Vehicle identified by serial {
 o String brand
 o String model
 o String color
 o Status status
 o Double price
 o String serial
}
asset Order identified by orderId{
 o String orderId
 o Vehicle item
 --> Customer customer
}

transaction PlaceOrder {
    o String orderId
    --> Vehicle item
    o Customer customer
}
```

script.js

```
/**
 * @param {org.isn.shop.PlaceOrder}orderRequest  
 * @transaction
 */

async function placeOrder(orderRequest){

    const factory = getFactory(); 
    const customerRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry("org.isn.customer.Customer");
    const customerExists = await customerRegistry.exists(orderRequest.customer.email);

    if(!customerExists){ 
        const customer = factory.newResource("org.isn.customer","Customer",orderRequest.customer.email);
        customer.firstName = orderRequest.customer.firstName;
        customer.lastName = orderRequest.customer.lastName;
        customer.email = orderRequest.customer.email;
        customer.password = orderRequest.customer.password;
        await customerRegistry.add(customer);
    }else{
        const customer = await customerRegistry.get(orderRequest.customer.email);    
    }

    const order = await factory.newResource("org.isn.shop","Order",orderRequest.orderId);
    order.customer = customer.getIdentifier();
    order.item = orderRequest.item;
    const orderRegistry = await getAssetRegistry("org.isn.shop.Order");
    await orderRegistry.add(order);

    const PlaceOrderEvent = factory.newEvent("org.isn.shop","PlaceOrderEvent");
    placeOrderEvent.order = order;
    emit(placeOrderEvent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`o Customer customer` needs to become `--> Customer customer` then you will be able to reference `orderRequest.customer.firstName` etc also not sure you need `order.customer = customer.getIdentifier();`  might need to become `order.customer.email = customer.getIdentifier();`

Comment: the code works if i removed customerExists condition checking. Please find the pastebin https://pastebin.com/xhdqG8TG . (else part also was commented)

Answer (score 0):

The following version of the Model and the JS will work for a new and existing customer:

```
    namespace org.isn.customer

participant Customer identified by email {
 o String firstName
 o String lastName
 o String email
 o String password
}

enum Status{
o ACTIVE
o OFF_THE_ROAD  
}

asset Vehicle identified by serial {
 o String brand
 o String model
 o String color
 o Status status
 o Double price
 o String serial
}

asset Order identified by orderId{
 o String orderId
 --> Vehicle item
 --> Customer customer
}

transaction PlaceOrder {
    o String orderId
    --> Vehicle item
    o Customer customer
}


/**
 * @param {org.isn.customer.PlaceOrder}orderRequest  
 * @transaction
 */

async function placeOrder(orderRequest){
    const factory = getFactory(); 
    const customerRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry("org.isn.customer.Customer");
    const customerExists = await customerRegistry.exists(orderRequest.customer.email);
    if(!customerExists){ 
        var customer = factory.newResource("org.isn.customer","Customer",orderRequest.customer.email);
        customer.firstName = orderRequest.customer.firstName;
        customer.lastName = orderRequest.customer.lastName;
        customer.email = orderRequest.customer.email;
        customer.password = orderRequest.customer.password;
        await customerRegistry.add(customer);
    }else{
        var customer = await customerRegistry.get(orderRequest.customer.email);    
    }
    const order = await factory.newResource("org.isn.customer","Order",orderRequest.orderId);
    order.customer = factory.newRelationship("org.isn.customer","Customer",customer.getIdentifier());
    order.item = orderRequest.item;
    const orderRegistry = await getAssetRegistry("org.isn.customer.Order");
    await orderRegistry.add(order);
}
```

Please note the following:
In the **Order asset** I have changed the `o Vehicle` to be `--> Vehicle item` to match up with the Transaction.

I have also used `var customer` in both the if and else code.

(To make mine work I had to use the same namespace, but perhaps you had separate .cto files)